# I've seen two techniques for implementing in-app billing in android, but I don't know which is more standard or correct

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I've found two seemingly conflicting google-published explanations of how to set up in-app billing. Which is more up to date? Which one is more standard? I'm not asking for unfounded opinions. I would like to know if there is a reason that one is better than the other (i.e. newer, more-standard practice, etc.)

[Option 1](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html), which uses a service connection, or [Option 2](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html), which calls the following to set up a connection with google play:

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
    ...
});
```

So far I've implemented option 2, but I've noticed that there are a number of stack traces thrown and other general problems, so I'm leaning towards option 1.

Comment: You should rewrite this to ask about whether technique A or technique B is better. As written, it's off-topic. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Updated. Any better?

Comment: it's better, but it still would benefit from having more of the essential information in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow Option 2's method of getting the aidl file, you will get the more up-to-date file. That leads me to believe that option 2 is the more up-to-date solution, despite its few problems.

Further, after more research it looks like if you use option 1's tutorial you will have to create your own async tasks, as calling the methods they suggest on the UI thread will cause it to freeze. Since in Option 2 the method calls include the word "async," this leads me to believe they are more evolved and up-to-date.

Hope this helps someone else!